# How to change (title) view of ExpandableListView depending on Object that has created it?

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I am fighting for a week now with a "getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)" method.

I've found one key thing:

- listPosition and convertView are NOT always related

  ```
  @Override
  public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      String listTitle = getGroup(listPosition).toString();

      if (convertView == null) {
          LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.
                  getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
      }

      TextView listTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);


      Item item = (Item) getGroup(listPosition); //Returns item from ArrayList

      // The part behind && should ensure that no wrong passes happen. But they do anyway.
      if (item.AllFound() && item.toString(Item.BASE_TITLE_FORMAT).equals(listTitleTextView.getText())){
          //listTitleTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
          convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
      }

      listTitleTextView.setText(listTitle);
      return convertView;
  }
  ```

What is this:

- Background color of convertView (or listTitleTextView) should change to GREEN if item at groupPosition returns TRUE from method AllFound()
- A lot of times, the convertView gets colored even though it should not.

But that's just my gibberish. I am willing to rewrite the whole thing.

So how to change (title) view of ExpandableList depending on Object that has created it? (Obviously you cannot depend on listPosition so how should I retrieve the correct object?)

Answer (score 0):

the convertView will be reused, consider all situation

```
if (item.AllFound() && item.toString(Item.BASE_TITLE_FORMAT).equals(listTitleTextView.getText())){
    //listTitleTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
} else{
 **Add code here to set backgroundColor** 
}
```